# EC2 instance Reachable with public DNS but unrechable through public @ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I launch an EC2 instance with security group that have an inbound  `SSH through port 22 from 0.0.0.0/0`. In my local machine I can connect to this instance by using its public DNS like that:

```
ssh ec2-user@ec2-54-144-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com -i KeyPair.pem
```

However, I cannot reach the same instance by using its public ip address

```
ssh -v ec2-user@54.144.XX.XXX -i KeyPair.pem 
OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.144.XX.XXX [54.144.XX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.144.XX.XXX port 22: Network is unreachable
ssh: connect to host 54.144.XX.XXX port 22: Network is unreachable
```

This is also my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Your true public IP in `ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com` is the X's.  Are you trying to connect to an IP in the range 172.16. 0.0 to 172.31. 255.255?  That is an internal IP.  You could connect to it if, for example, your machine was with others in a VPC.

Comment: @stdunbar No, the public ip address of the instance is 54.144.XX.XXX

Comment: Is that the same as the X's?  You should be able to do `ssh ec2-user@XX-XXX-XX-XXX -i KeyPair.pem`

Comment: @stdunbar But I can't. This is why I ask the question :(

Comment: I'd encourage you to ask this on https://serverfault.com as stack overflow is really for programming questions.  They may some additional insights as to what is going on.

Comment: @stdunbar ok, Thanks for your help